# Programatically focus a UI element that was re-enabled in the prior statement

Tags: c#, wpf, tab-ordering

I'm developing a form and one of the requirements for it is that the majority of the fields be disabled until the first two have been completed.  For the sake of usability I want it set up so after you tab out of the second field (Field_Two.LostFocus) the rest of the fields are enabled, displayed, and the first of those fields is focused.  The code that I have currently sets all fields' visibility to visibility.hidden at startup.  What it currently does is focus Field_One (next in the tab order of enabled fields), but I've confirmed that the conditions are properly satisfied and that execution proceeds past the return statement.

Field.beenFocused is a variable I've created that is initialized as false and then set to true when the Field is focused for the first time, my Field class extends TextBox; all of my controls save Field_One and Field_Two are in Stackpanels.

C#

```
        void Field_Two_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Field_Three.beenFocused)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Field_One.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Field_Two.Text))
                return;

            foreach (object u in ApplicationGrid.Children)
                if (u.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel))
                        ((StackPanel)u).IsEnabled = true;

            do { Field_Three.Focus(); }
            while (!Field_Three.beenFocused);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't focus a disabled element.  You'll have to enable it, then focus on it.  Your question seems to address this ("the conditions are properly satisfied"), but it is a little vague - What conditions?  If you can separate out what you are expecting and what you are seeing it might make it easier.  What I get is that the basic problem is "if I enable a control in the LostFocus handler, then it will still be skipped over in the tab order.  It will only be considered in the tab order when it is enabled before tabbing".  Does that sound right?

Comment: Merlyn, your description of my problem is incredibly concise.  I think that the question I'm really asking, though, is along the lines of (to steal heavily from your description): if I enable a control in the LostFocus handler, then attempt to focus it, why does the element that whose focusing triggered the LostFocus event (in my code, Field_One which is tabbed to causing Field_Two's LostFocus handler to be called) retains focus despite the newlyEnabledElement.Focus() call

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling/disabling in a `TextChanged` event, rather than a `LostFocus` event.

Here's some sample code.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" TextChanged="ValidateInitialFieldsOnChange"
                 Height="23" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox2" TextChanged="ValidateInitialFieldsOnChange"
                 Height="23" Width="120" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox3" IsEnabled="False" Height="23" Width="120" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ValidateInitialFieldsOnChange(object sender,
            TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.IsEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text)
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

It would be fairly trivial to adapt this code to suit your scenario, and wouldn't require manually setting focus.  You could probably rely on tab order instead.

But if tab order *doesn't* help, you can still use a combination of these approaches to solve the problem.  Set focus in the `LostFocus` event, and enable in teh `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Note that if you haven't created a lot of code yet, I'd suggest looking at [the MVVM design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).  My example code doesn't use it because it seemed like your question already had a lot of code-behind.